# expected primary-expression before 'char' error message

Tags: c++

I can't figure this one out and am pulling my hair out. I've looked at various threads (here & elsewhere) you have on the same "expected primary-expression" issue and believe I'm close to the answer, specifically on the ones dealing templates, but I just can't piece it together. I think I have a syntactical issue and have always found the syntax for declarations of new templated instantiations a bit tricky.

I spent a long time coding a Binary Search Tree that can traverse, insert, etc... My test program inserts different characters (chars) at indeces of different keys (integers). I need to test the program by simply displaying those elements (in order) using my traverseInorder method. Within my test program, I first dynamically-create a BinarySearchTree and also create a Visitor which I use to visit the tree in order to display those elements. However, this is where something (probably my syntax for Visitor) is going wrong.

My program comes up with the following three errors:

1) main.cpp|33|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'

2) RootNode.cpp|27|error: conflicting return type specified for 'bool RootNode::insert(KEY, DATA) [with KEY = int; DATA = char]'
3) Node.h|22|error:   overriding 'void Node::insert(KEY, DATA) [with KEY = int; DATA = char]'

4) BinaryNode.cpp|16|error: 'int BinaryNode::m_tKey' is private
5) RootNode.cpp|35|error: within this context|

I'm not sure if the errors are actually related, but the first is the most important one I'm worried about.

My complete code is as follows:

---

"RootNode.cpp"

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Visitor.h"
#include "BinaryNode.cpp"

template <class KEY, class DATA>
class RootNode: public Node<KEY,DATA>
{
    private:
    KEY m_tKey;
    DATA m_tData;

    BinaryNode<KEY,DATA> *m_pcFirstLink;

    public:
    RootNode():m_pcFirstLink(NULL){;}

    ~RootNode(){if (m_pcFirstLink) {delete m_pcFirstLink; m_pcFirstLink=NULL;}}

     bool insert(KEY key,DATA data)
     {
        bool m_bAdded;

        if (m_pcFirstLink) m_bAdded=m_pcFirstLink->insert(key,data);
        else
        {
            BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>* p_cBinaryNode = new BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>(key,data);
            p_cBinaryNode->m_tKey=key;
            p_cBinaryNode->m_tData=data;
            m_pcFirstLink=p_cBinaryNode;
            m_bAdded=true;
        }

        return m_bAdded;
     }

     void traverseInorder(Visitor<DATA> visitor)
     {
        if (m_pcFirstLink) m_pcFirstLink->traverseInorder(visitor);
     }

};
```

---

"BinarySearchTree.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "RootNode.cpp"
#include "Visitor.h"
#include "FredTreeFullException.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <class KEY,class DATA>
class BinarySearchTree
{
    private:
    KEY m_tKey;
    DATA m_tData;
    int count;

    RootNode<KEY,DATA>* m_pcRoot;

    public:
    BinarySearchTree():count(0)
    {
    m_pcRoot = new RootNode<KEY,DATA>;
    }

    int getSize(){return count;}

    bool insert(KEY key, DATA data)
    {
    bool m_bAdded;

    if (!isFull())
        {
            m_bAdded=m_pcRoot->insert(key,data);
            if (m_bAdded) {count++;}
        }
    // if trying to insert into the binary tree while already full, throw an exception!
    else {throw FredTreeFullException();}
    }

    bool isEmpty(){(count==0)?true:false;}

    bool isFull(){return false;}

    void traverseInorder(Visitor<DATA> visitor)
    {
        if (!isFull()) m_pcRoot.traverseInorder(visitor);
    }

};
```

---

"BinaryNode.cpp"

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Visitor.h"

template <class KEY, class DATA>
class BinaryNode: public Node<KEY,DATA>
{
private:
    KEY m_tKey;
    DATA m_tData;

    BinaryNode<KEY,DATA> *m_pcLeft,*m_pcRight;

public:
    BinaryNode(KEY key,DATA data)
    {
        m_tKey(key);
        m_tData(data);
        m_pcLeft(0);
        m_pcRight(0);
    }

    ~BinaryNode()
    {
        if (m_pcLeft)
        {
            delete m_pcLeft;
            m_pcLeft=0; // additionally setting to NULL for best practice
        }
        if (m_pcRight)
        {
            delete m_pcRight;
            m_pcRight=0; // additionally setting to NULL for best practice
        }
    }

    bool insert(KEY key,DATA data)
    {
        bool m_bAdded=true;
        if (key==(m_tKey))
        {
            m_tData=data;
            m_bAdded=false;
        }
        else if (key<m_tKey)
        {
            if (m_pcLeft) {m_bAdded = m_pcLeft->insert(key,data);}
            else
            {
                BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>* p_cBinaryNode = new BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>(key,data);
                p_cBinaryNode->m_tKey=key;
                p_cBinaryNode->m_tData=data;
                m_pcLeft=p_cBinaryNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_pcRight) {m_bAdded = m_pcRight->insert(key,data);}
            else
            {
                BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>* p_cBinaryNode = new BinaryNode<KEY,DATA>(key,data);
                p_cBinaryNode->m_tKey=key;
                p_cBinaryNode->m_tData=data;
                m_pcRight=p_cBinaryNode;
            }
        }

        return m_bAdded;
    }

    void traverseInorder(Visitor<DATA> visitor)
    {
        if (m_pcLeft) m_pcLeft->traverseInorder(visitor);
        visitor.visit(m_tData);
        if (m_pcRight) m_pcRight->traverseInorder(visitor);
    }
};
```

---

"Node.h"

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include "Visitor.h"

template <class KEY, class DATA>
class Node
{
    private:
    KEY m_tKey;
    DATA m_tData;

    public:
    virtual void insert(KEY key, DATA data)=0;
    virtual void traverseInorder(Visitor<DATA> visitor)=0;
};

#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

---

"FredTreeFullException.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FredTreeFullException
{
public:
   FredTreeFullException()
   {
       cout << endl << "The Tree is Full!" << endl;
   }
};
```

---

"Visitor.h"

```
#ifndef VISITOR_H
#define VISITOR_H

#include <iostream>

template <class DATA>
class Visitor
{
    public:
    void visit(DATA data){std::cout << std::endl << "Data: " << data << std::endl;};

};

#endif // VISITOR_H_INCLUDED
```

---

"main.cpp"

```
// Driver / test program

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include "BinarySearchTree.cpp"
#include "Visitor.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
    Visitor<char> cVisitor;
    BinarySearchTree<int,char>* cBinarySeachTree = new BinarySearchTree<int,char>;

    cBinarySeachTree->insert(3,'c');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(5,'e');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(2,'b');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(7,'g');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(4,'d');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(1,'a');
    cBinarySeachTree->insert(6,'f');

    cout << "The binary tree's contents in order, are as follows:" << endl;
    cBinarySeachTree->traverseInorder(cVisitor<char>.visit);
    }
    catch(FredTreeFullException &TFE)
    {
        FredTreeFullException();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what ugliness #include "some.cpp" and new in main for no reason!

Comment: Line 33 of the `main.cpp` you posted is blank. The code you posted needs to be *exactly* the same as the code you're compiling. At least add comments on the affected lines. Try narrowing down your source code to something *much* shorter that still exhibits the same errors. (And don't use `#include` for `.cpp` files.)

Comment: Most of this code can be removed without affecting the problem. Start chopping!

Comment: The convention is to write the implementation for template classes in a header file, and then include that header file instead of including a .cpp file.

Comment: @PeteBecker -no, no :)  Code is only for writing - you get someone else to do all the heavy-lifting of fixing compile/link errors and debugging :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the errors quite easily by looking at the code lines in the error messages. I'm having to guess, since the line numbers in the pile of code you've posted don't match, but:

First:

```
main.cpp|33|error: expected primary-expression before 'char'
```

`cVisitor<char>.visit` is gibberish. It should just be `cVisitor`.

Second:

```
RootNode.cpp|27|error: conflicting return type specified
```

You declared the virtual function with no return type:

```
virtual void insert(KEY key, DATA data)=0;
```

then tried to override it with a function returning `bool`:

```
bool insert(KEY key,DATA data)
```

Decide what the return type should be, and change all the declarations to match.

Third:

```
BinaryNode.cpp|16|error: 'int BinaryNode::m_tKey' is private
```

You can only access private members of `BinaryNode` within that class and its friends. To access it from `RootNode`, either make it public, or provide a public accessor, or make `RootNode` a friend, depending on your views on encapsulation.